# Trying to figure out why batch file is running twice

Tags: loops, dos, batch-file

i am sure this is something obvious, but i cant seem to figure it out, for some reason, the batch file i have pasted below always runs twice instead of once when it hits :rename. Could someone tell me what the issue here is? This is related to the 2 other questions  - [Looking for a way to execute a batch file once a folder hits 10 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262642/looking-for-a-way-to-execute-a-batch-file-once-a-folder-hits-10-files) and [copy and rename files of a certain extension via batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262508/copy-and-rename-files-of-a-certain-extension-via-batch-file)

Here is the batch file --- >

```
rem Counting files...
set /a count = 0
for /f "tokens=*" %%P IN ('dir "H:\" /A /b') do (set /a count += 1)



rem 5 or more files?



if %count% GEQ 5 call :rename



:rename
SET count=1
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.jpg') DO (call :rename_next "%%G")

goto:copy

:rename_next
ren "%1" %count%.jpg

Pause
set /a count+=1

goto:eof

:copy
xcopy c:\photo\*.jpg c:\photo\files /Y
Pause
```

Comment: thank you, that worked and made sense. I added a goto:eof to exit out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
if %count% GEQ 5 call :rename
```

is calling `:rename`. After rename returns, the code continues after this if, which happens to be `:rename` again.

Replace with this code to see what's happening:

```
echo before call
if %count% GEQ 5 call :rename
echo after call
```